# Converting to Real Dollars in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a series of charts in Tableau that track money over time that I want to convert to "real" dollars using the consumer price index. I know that I could create a calculated field for each year that will get me the correct result, but is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by easier. You could try a lookup table with that contains the conversion values and blend that into your current dashboard. One way or another, you'll have to do a calculation to translate into "real" dollars.

Comment: Thanks Bernardo. This calculation seemed common enough that I wasn't sure if someone out there had a more elegant solution, or if there was any built in functionality to deal with CPI. I am still new to Tableau and I am always finding new features, and I wanted to double check if this was one of them.